# How to prevent browser trying to auto-validate email address field?

Tags: html, validation, cakephp

My input is as follows:

```
<input id="AdministratorEmail" type="email" maxlength="255" novalidate="novalidate" name="data[Administrator][email]">
```

Why is the browser (have tested in Firefox and Chrome) still trying to auto-validate the email field for me when I have the `novalidate` attribute specified?

How can I prevent this from happening?

I am using CakePHP if it is of any relevance.

Comment: See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements and the `'formnovalidate' => true` part.

Comment: @mark Thanks. I was adding `novalidate => true` to the form's `inputDefaults` array instead, which is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the `novalidate` attribute on individual inputs, which is incorrect. As [mata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350899/mata) pointed out, it is not a recognised attribute of inputs, but an attribute of the [HTML form tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/form.html) itself.

**Solution**

```
<form novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="email" name="email" />
</form>
```

As you can see, you do not need to change the type to `type="text"`, and like any other boolean attribute, `novalidate` can be added in multiple ways and all are acceptable.

```
<form novalidate>  <!-- Also acceptable -->
```

**Solution for CakePHP**

```
echo $this->Form->create('MyModel', array(
    'novalidate' => true
));
echo $this->Form->input('email');
```

Thanks to [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461173/mark) for this.

Comment: In my smartphone app, type="email" is different from type="text" in behavior.  If the input type is text and I use an email address for that input, after I press the period key, a space is automatically put after the period and the next word has a capital letter.  The email type doesn't do that, is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `type="email"`.
Set this to `type="text"`. It will work the same but without the validation.

This is thanks to built-in email validation that most major browsers use. I have personally never heard of the `novalidate` attribute.

EDIT: I've just read up on novalidate, you should type it like so:

```
<form novalidate>
```

instead of

```
<form novalidate="novalidate">
```

Comment: I don't think it matters how you enter the novalidate attribute, it is valid either way. I think the problem is the `type="email"` maybe but is there a solution that allows me to keep type email?

Comment: @BadHorsie Well as far as I know it should be fine to use type="text" instead. The only reason you would want type="email" is for the validation, which you stated is not what you want. Have you tried to see if <input novalidate> works?

Comment: novalidate isn't valid on [input email](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html) tags, only on [form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/form.html)

Comment: @mata I never said novalidate was valid on email tags. But you're right, it is only valid on form tags. I will edit it ASAP.